# Problem with Chrome Browser cookies for IBM Cloud Hyper Protect DBaaS

Tags: ibm-cloud

When I was clicking to enter the new IBM Cloud Hyper Protect DBaaS Beta service, I ran into the following problem and saw the following error message. To resolve it, I tried clearing Chrome cash and cookies.

Problem:

[image: Error picture]

Am using Chrome Browser and when I click to enter the new IBM Cloud Hyper Protect DBaaS Beta service I get this error about cookies:

When I close the message box it just sits and spins up the error again.

I happened to have Firefox as well and when I used that I could access the cluster overview of Hyper Protect DBaaS just fine.

I tried clearing cookies and cache but am still getting the error on Chrome.

My version seems to be one of the supported browsers:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/hyper-protect-dbaas/help-issues.html#supported-browsers

Answer (score -2):

Ralf, here is the answer hope it will help you ....

[image]